# C# - How to get synchronous UI update from the InvokeRequired pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, synchronous, begininvoke

I have a number of threads to append text to a rich text box.
With Invoke(), I very easily get deadlock between the main UI thread and the worker threads.
With BeginInvoke(), I get async UI update, which I do not want. I want the texts appear in the text box instantly, not at some later stage that I can't determine.

How do I do my task?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding my earlier answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot magically run on the UI thread without touching the UI thread.
If you want to call `Invoke`, you need to make the UI thread stop waiting for the background threads.

However, you should just call `BeginInvoke` instead.
`BeginInvoke` isn't any less instant than `Invoke`; the only difference is that `Invoke` forces the calling thread to wait until the UI thread has a chance to run the delegate.

You would call `Invoke` if the background thread needs to wait for the UI thread to run the delegate (eg, if it returns a value).
In normal cases, you should always call `BeginInvoke`; there's usually no point in making the background thread wait until the UI thread is free.

Comment: Thank you very much SLaks. After struggling with threading for 2 days now I roughly understand how things work.